# Update array values for rows and columns given by a condition

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following two arrays:

```
a = np.mat('5;5;1;4;3;2;1;5;3')
b = np.zeros((9,9))
```

The array `a` is a cluster assignment, where each object (represented by a row) is assigned to a given cluster (represented by a number). I have multiple such cluster assignments and would like to count in the array `b` how often each pair of objects co-occur in the same cluster. In Matlab, I'd write something like the following:

```
b(a==5,a==5) = b(a==5,a==5) + 1
```

The output would be:

```
 b =
      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

For example, `b(2,8) == 1` (using Matlab indexing starting at 1) because both elements `2` and `8` are in cluster `5`.

The indexing system is quite different in NumPy and I was wondering how to do the same thing there?

**UPDATE:**

[zhangxaochen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555826/265289) using `b[m&m.T]+=1` gives correct results. I've also come up with the following way:

```
c = np.nonzero(a == 5)[0]
b[c.T,c] +=1
```

Are there any strong reasons to use one over the other? I work with large arrays with tens of thousands of rows/columns.

Comment: Can you give an example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [1149]: m=(a==5)

In [1150]: b[m+m.T]+=1

In [1151]: b
Out[1151]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

**UPDATE:**

From your comment I guess what you need is `&`:

```
In [1220]: b[m&m.T]+=1

In [1221]: b
Out[1221]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

**BENCHMARK:**

```
In [1285]: %%timeit
      ...: d=1000
      ...: b=np.zeros((d,d))
      ...: a=arange(d)>(d/2)
      ...: at=a[:,None]
      ...: b[a&at]+=1
      ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 32.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. The output array has value 1 in position (0,2), which is incorrect since the two elements are in different clusters (5 and 1, respectively).

Comment: Cheers, I've added the example output and it currently gives correct results. However, is it efficient? If I understood it correctly, you need to create a temporary array with `good.shape[0]^2` elements, which can get quite pricey for large arrays.

Comment: @JohnManak yes it creates a tem 2D array using numpy broadcasting, but I don't think it's too much pricey, updated